# Extract the highest value of each day

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table that is full of transactions transactionIDs and datetime fields.
As you would guess, the datetime field and transactionIDs are constantly increasing and the balance field is either increasing / staying the same / or decreasing.

I would like to extract the highest transactionID and its corresponding balance at the end of every day.

Thank you in advance for your time and assistance.

Sample Table Format:

### transactionID|date (datetime)|amount|balance|

Comment: How about adding the table descriptions for MySQL, that would help me and others solve your problem

Comment: Do not write "using php" when this is just a database query you need.

Comment: I apologize for adding the php part.  I have updated the question to show a sample of what the structure of the table looks like.  The balance can go up or down with each transaction and I would like to get the last transaction of each day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  t1.`date`,
  t1.transactionID,
  t2.balance
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      `date`,
      MAX(transactionID) AS `transactionID`
    FROM
      table
    GROUP BY
      DATE(`date`)
  ) t1
INNER JOIN
  table t2
ON
  t2.transactionID = t1.transactionID
ORDER BY
  t1.`date`
```

Comment: I apologize for not having a table sample in my original post; I have updated the op.  How does this query tell the database to look at each and every day?

Comment: The `GROUP BY DATE(date)` says to return one row per date in the subselect, `MAX(transactionID)` says to return the highest transactionID for that date, and you join this to the same table to get the balance matching that `transactionID`.

Comment: Thank you for the explination Dan, it worked like a charm.  I apologize for not specifying some of the information needed to formulate a good question.  What does the t1 and t2 do, setup temp tables?  Thanks again.

Comment: They are just aliases to make the query unambiguous. You can change t1 and t2 to any two words.

Comment: why using a self join, instead of selecting balance in the inner query also?

Comment: Because the inner query is a `GROUP BY` -- you have a number of `transactionID`s and a number of `balance`s within each group of rows that will be collapsed because they share the same date. Your only options for choosing which row becomes the representative of the group are the aggregate functions, like `MIN` and `MAX`. None of those functions will maintain the relationship between the `transactionID` and its balance. You must do a join to get the balance corresponding to the `MAX(transactionID)` selected from the group. If you understand how `GROUP BY` reduces rows it's clear.

Comment: Perhaps I should ask another question but what would change if I wanted to run the query by hour, week or month?

Comment: You would have to change three things: add `HOUR(date)` to the `SELECT` list of the subquery, add `t1.HOUR(date)` to the `SELECT` list of the outer query, and change the `GROUP BY` to be `HOUR(date)` instead of `DATE(date)`. Same for `WEEK()` or `MONTH()`. You need to use backticks around the name of your `date` column which I can't include in this comment because `date` is a reserved word in MySQL. You'll probably also want to add additional `WHERE` clauses, or `GROUP BY` `YEAR`/`MONTH`/`DATE` in addition to the other time period... for example, to differentiate 7/2011 from 7/2010.

Comment: Thank you very much, by far the most useful and helpful information I have been able to come across.  I really need to register an account on here so that I can give you more credit than just marking the answer correct.  Thank you for your time and your precise answers

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT balance FROM table WHERE table.created > TODAY() ORDER BY transactionID DESC LIMIT 1
```

`table.created` is the column containing the creation date of the record,

This query should give you the transactionID for just the current day. Do you need it for an interval of days? - in that case, the following query should do it

```
 SELECT balance FROM 
      (SELECT transactionID, balance FROM table ORDER BY transactionID DESC) 
 GROUP BY DAYOFYEAR(table.created)
```

Comment: Your second query is very wrong in many ways. Try it out. Not only will it not run, but if you fix the obvious errors it'll give you the wrong results. You're neither reading his question nor answering it.

Comment: Now you were right, thx for the observation - but your first comment and the downvote were totally inappropriate

Comment: Tudor, just a tip: Avoid desperately to use user-functions or subqueries in WHERE clause. It's a serious performance-eater. :)

Comment: @armandomiani - you are right - `GROUP BY` is executed before the `ORDER BY`, that is why i put the subquery - I needed the `DAYOFYEAR` function to be able to group by day the records,

Comment: Your subquery will select every `transactionID,balance` pair from the table. Your outer query will select one balance from each set of rows having the same `DAYOFYEAR(table.created)` value. You fail to specify how this balance should be chosen from the group, which is invalid SQL; MySQL will not throw an error, but as the manual says, the behavior is undefined. MySQL is free to choose *any* of the balance values from each `DAYOFYEAR` group, and it's unlikely to randomly choose the one corresponding to the row with the highest `transactionID` for that date, which is what the question asks for.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you that insert unix_timestamp as your date field on your table.and use this query to fetch heighest transactionID :

```
$query = 'SELECT MAX (transactionID) FROM [ TABLE NAME ] WHERE [ DATE FIELD NAME ] BETWEEN' .  strtotime("today 23:59"). ' AND ' . strtotime("today")
```

Comment: Who r u ? r u founder of this site ? just answer to questions and keep your idea for yourself and talk respectably